# Infimum and supremum involving trigonometry

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

Find, if there exist, infimum and supremum of the set
$$S:=\{[\cos((m^2+n)\pi)+\cos((m^2-n)\pi)]\frac{2-3m+2n-3mn}{2n+2mn};m,n\in \mathbb N\}$$
$$m,n \in \mathbb N \implies (m^2+n),(m^2-n)\in \mathbb Z$$
The sum of cosines transformed into product:
$$\cos((m^2+n)\pi)+\cos((m^2-n)\pi)=2\cos(m^2\pi)\cos(n\pi)=\pm2,$$ which depends if $m,n\in \mathbb N$ are odd or even, so there are $4$ cases, $2$ $distinct$.
I simplified the initial expression and got:
$$\cos(m^2\pi)\cos(n\pi)\frac{(2-3m)(1+n)}{n(1+m)}$$
As mentioned before: $\cos(m^2\pi)\cos(n\pi)=\pm 1.$

Can you suggest how to continue and finish the task?
Should I ramify the expression I got into more cases or $fix$ $the$ $values$ $1$ first for $n$, then for $m$ (as I was already suggested in a similar task today if you've seen the post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul suggests, you can write each element $s$ of $S$ as $$ s=(-1)^m\left(-3 +\frac 5{1+m}\right)\times (-1)^n\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)\text{ for some }m,n\in \Bbb N.$$$$\implies |s|=\bigg|(-1)^m\left(-3 +\frac 5{1+m}\right)\times (-1)^n\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)\bigg|=\bigg|-3 +\frac 5{1+m}\bigg|\times \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)\leq |-3|\times\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)=3\left(1 + \frac 1n\right) \leq 3\times\bigg(1+\frac 11\bigg)=6$$$$\implies -6\leq s\leq 6,\forall s\in S.$$ Now the sequence $\{a_k\}$ defined by $$a_k=(-1)^{2k}\left(-3 +\frac 5{1+(2k)}\right)\times (-1)^1\left(1 + \frac 11\right)\in S$$ converges to $6$.

Also the sequence $\{b_k\}$ defined by $$b_k=(-1)^{2k+1}\left(-3 +\frac 5{1+(2k+1)}\right)\times (-1)^{1}\left(1 + \frac {1}{1}\right)\in S$$ converges to $-6$.

So $\text{inf}(S)=-6$ and $\sup(S)=6$.

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that $S = \{f(m)g(n) \mid m,n \in \Bbb N\}$, where
$$f(m) = (-1)^m\frac{2-3m}{1+m} = (-1)^m\left(-3 +\frac 5{1+m}\right)$$
and
$$g(n) = (-1)^n\frac{1+n}n = (-1)^m\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)$$

Also note that you will need to examine the behavior of $f$ and $g$ separately for $m, n$ even and odd.